# When I try to compile and .exe I get ImportError: No module named six

Tags: python-2.7, pyinstaller, py2exe, cx-freeze, six

I've tried making an exe from a program using py2exe, cx_freeze and pyinstaller. All of which give me an error 'ImportError: No module named six' when I go to launch the .exe

The .exe is able to be created. I've looked through the forums and all of them say to pip install six (it's already installed). I've tried uninstalling and re-installing six.

One post mentioned uninstalling matplotlib, so I did that.

When I instlalled pyinstaller one of the requirements was that six be installed! So this is very baffling.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://i289.photobucket.com/albums/ll233/89733/stacked_help_zpsnrvlayj4.jpg

After Gabriel asked for the screenshot I took a closer look.

pip install urllib3 --upgrade solved the issue, which I found here:

https://github.com/transifex/transifex-client/issues/103

Answer (score 0):

When you create a .*exe* file using *cx_freeze* it kind of compiles all the needed libraries into the .*exe* folder, you probably had to configurate a setup file from *cx_freeze* to be able to create the .*exe*, right? There you must "tell" *cx_freeze* which libraries are going to be needed when someone runs the program.

Keep in mind that when you create a .*exe* you dont need to have *python* neither *six* to run it.

Comment: I added 'six' to the include list. Didn't help.

Comment: Sorry for late response:
http://i289.photobucket.com/albums/ll233/89733/stacked_help_zpsnrvlayj4.jpg