# ImportError: No module named six - Already Installed six

Tags: python-2.7

I've installed six with the command

```
pip install six
```

and if I print the version with:

```
python -c "import six; print (six.__version__)"
```

the version of six is listed as:

```
1.10.0
```

I'm trying to convert my Python program into stand-alone executable.
I've tried py2exe and PyInstaller. Both create the package fine but when I run the main.exe I get a brief flash with the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 9, in <module>
  File "requests\__init__.pyc", line 58, in <module>
  File "requests\utils.pyc", line 26, in <module>
  File "requests\compat.pyc", line 7, in <module>
  File "requests\packages\__init__.pyc", line 7, in <module>
  File "urllib3\__init__.pyc", line 10, in <module>
  File "urllib3\connectionpool.pyc", line 30, in <module>
  File "urllib3\packages\six.pyc", line 5, in <module>
ImportError: No module named six
```

Can someone help me understand how to use this traceback to fix my issue?

I have tried to include six in my setup.py for p2exe:

```
from distutils.core import setup
import py2exe
setup(windows=[{"script":"main.py"}], options={"py2exe":{"includes":["six"]}})
```

But alas it did not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
pip install urllib3 --upgrade
```

solved the issue.

Found this here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44071536/3804349

Comment: I still have the problem after doing this.